# Upload video of more than 2MB. using multi part request android

Tags: android, video, file-upload, multipartform-data

I want to upload videos of more than 2Mb but i am not able to upload it.

i tried to upload with retrofit but i am getting

> timeoutException

then i tried with multipart request request but i am not able to upload it.

> there is no problem on server side because from IOS app we are able to
>   upload the video which mean server configurations are correct.

here is the code that i am using to upload the video.

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        }
        else
        {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObjectData = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjectData.put("api_key", "2fdaeddaeef77d488a5_5f2e");
                jsonObjectData.put("email", "example@gmail.com");
                jsonObjectData.put("access_token", "e1507300a57bf999accb593c1f04c9bdbdce5da7a9086160c4497e160da0ff74");
                jsonObjectData.put("request_token", "188d25eda1688119f2e133885a75726d2963e5f2eef4f87524b16da248544607");
                jsonObjectData.put("request_timestamp", "1459333407");

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL("http://admin.eyesoncrime.co.uk/api/v1/videos/upload");
                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("data", jsonObjectData.toString());
                conn.setRequestProperty("file_name", sourceFile.getName());

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_upl\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getContentEncoding();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    +" C:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("server Exception", "Upload file to server Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }
```

UPDATE 1:

Now I tried with OkHttp as suggested by @BNK  [here](https://github.com/ngocchung/MultipartOkHttp) but getting the socket timeout exception

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 101;
    private final Context mContext = this;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "OkHttp";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private String filemanagerstring= "";
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = MediaType.parse("video/*");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    }

    public void upload(String filemanagerstring){

        JSONObject jsonObjectData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObjectData.put("api_key", "2fdaeddaeef77d488a5_5f2e");
            jsonObjectData.put("email", "neerajrathi81@gmail.com");
            jsonObjectData.put("access_token", "e1507300a57bf999accb593c1f04c9bdbdce5da7a9086160c4497e160da0ff74");
            jsonObjectData.put("request_token", "188d25eda1688119f2e133885a75726d2963e5f2eef4f87524b16da248544607");
            jsonObjectData.put("request_timestamp", "1459333407");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File sourceFile = new File(filemanagerstring);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; file_name=\"" + sourceFile.getName() + "\"" + "\r\n"),
                        RequestBody.create(null, "Sample Text Content"))
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; data=\"" + jsonObjectData.toString() + "\"" + "\r\n"),
                        RequestBody.create(null, jsonObjectData.toString()))
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ECO_video.mp4\""),
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, sourceFile))
                .build();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://admin.eyesoncrime.co.uk/api/v1/videos/upload")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTextView.setText(e.toString());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                final String message = response.toString();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, message);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTextView.setText(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
    public void openGallery(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                filemanagerstring = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                upload(filemanagerstring);
            }
        }
    }

    // UPDATED!
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Please suggest any solution. Thanks.

Comment: You should increase your timeout limit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-a-timeout-in-retrofit-library

Comment: i have already tried this.. but no success,

Comment: You can try Volley at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley?lq=1, then set Timeout for the request, such as `jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`