# Volley delete request with body data not working

Tags: android, performance, android-volley, http-delete

hello everyone im facing a problem with volley delete request .

i working on task in user add or remove some contacts by it's id .

im using volley library for it.

API is tested  with postman and working fine.

```
private void AddContactInList(final Contacts contacts,int RequestMethod) {

JSONArray ContactArray = new JSONArray();

ContactArray.put(StoredContactid);

final String jsonStr = ContactArray.toString();

String URl =  OrganizationModel.getApiBaseUrl() + getOrgId() + "/lists/" + contacts.getId()+"/contacts";

Log.i(TAG,URl);

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(RequestMethod,URl,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Log.i(TAG,response.toString());

                try {

                    JSONArray mJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("contactIds");

                    contacts.setCode(String.valueOf(mJSONArray.length()));

                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    sqliteDataBaseHelper.changeContactUpdatedON(StoredContactid, String.valueOf(time));

                    sqliteDataBaseHelper.updateListContactsAndLength(contacts.getId(), mJSONArray.toString(), (mJSONArray.length()));

                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i(TAG,error.toString());
                String json = null;
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                    switch (response.statusCode) {
                        case 400:
                        case 405:
                            json = new String(response.data);
                            json = dataHelper.trimMessage(json, "message");
                            if (json != null) dataHelper.displayMessage(json);
                            break;
                    }

                }


            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        try {
            return jsonStr == null ? null : jsonStr.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                    jsonStr, "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + GetApiAccess());
        return headers;
    }
};
jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        9000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

}

Comment: i don't understand why pplz give down vote . if u can't reply then u don't have rights to dive down vote .

Comment: Pls try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553559/delete-request-with-header-and-parametes-volley/

Answer (score 0):

In my SQLite Database , the below code is working. Hope it may help you..

```
public void DeleteData(){
    btnDltData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer deleteRows = myDB.deleteData(editId.getText().toString());
                    if(deleteRows > 0)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Task Clear..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Task not Clear..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    editId.setText("");

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not related with local db it's server side probelm

Answer (score -1):

http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

try this, if problem didnt solve yet